# How to convert object to string in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, frontend

How to convert object to string in react js

```
var numeroToken = this.getSearchParams();

 getSearchParams(k){
         var p={};
         location.search.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,function(s,k,v){p[k]=v})
         return k?p[k]:p;
    }
```

I am trying to get the url from getSeatchParms() but it is returned as an object. How can I convert it to a String?

Comment: JSON.stringify(obj)

Answer (score 32):

I know this question is out of date, but if someone is looking for the answer (like I was) I could solve it with:
JSON.stringify(myObj)